# How to prevent fondant from crumbling?

Tags: fondant

I am making fondant based on this [recipe](http://eatnowcrylater.com/homemade-fondant) and it keeps on cracking when I try to lift it. Any suggestions on fixing this? Someone told me to add Glycerin. Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean *more* glycerine, since glycerine is already in your recipe. Add a little, knead it, add a little, knead it. You don't want to add too much: fondant is supposed to be firm, though not crumbly.

I always use [this](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/cooking-live/rolled-fondant-recipe/index.html) recipe. It seems simpler.